# UIWebview is not loading on IOS 6

Tags: ios6

`shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` and `webViewDidStartLoad` methods of `UIWebview` gets called once but after that the `activityIndicator` keeps on rotating (starts in `webViewDidStartLoad`) and none of the delegate methods `webViewDidFinishLoad` or `didFailLoadWithError` gets called. This is an issue on IOS 6 only.

Comment: You will probably get more help if you show the code. Without that, the only guess is that you didn't set UIWebViewDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me in iOS 5 and 6. Make sure you connect your outlets in Interface Builder. You should probably do some sort of check to see if Internet access is available. I'm doing it with the Apple Reachability class:

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface HelpWebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *webHelpURLString;

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView; //a web view starts loading
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;//web view finishes loading
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error; //web view failed to load

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
 #import "HelpWebViewController.h"
    #import "Reachability.h" // Needs System Configuration Framework

    @interface HelpWebViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation HelpWebViewController

    @synthesize webView = ivWebView;
    @synthesize activityIndicator = ivActivityIndicator;
    @synthesize webHelpURLString = ivWebHelpURLString;

    -(BOOL)reachable {
        Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"apple.com"];
        NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
        if(internetStatus == NotReachable) {
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];    

        NSURL *webHelpURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"support.apple.com"];
        NSURLRequest *myrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webHelpURL];
        [self.webView loadRequest:myrequest];
        self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

        if ([self reachable]) {
            NSLog(@"Reachable");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"cantOpenWebPageAlertTitle", @"Cannot Open Page - UIAlert can't open web page")
                                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"cantOpenWebPageAlertMessage", @"The page cannot be opened because you're not connected to the Internet.")
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"cantOpenWebPageAlertOKButton", @"OK - accept alert")
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            alert = nil;
        }
    }

    - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {

       [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
 }

    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }

    - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }

    @end
```